# How to show a dialog for an exception while halting the rest of the program flow?

Tags: android, exception, dialog

I have thought out an IMHO neat way of handling checked Exceptions, like so:

```
protected void handleException(Throwable e, int messageResourceId, ExceptionReaction reaction) {...}
```

which would be part of the app's BaseActivity (thus usable in all Activities).
Within this method I intend to show a dialog with the given message string and an OK button, and afterwards do something to react individually to the Exception (restart the activity, log the user out, reset database,...).
However, the dialog is started on the UI thread non-blockingly, and the Activities having called **handleException(...)** would just continue execution while the dialog is shown - which sucks, because something most probably has gone very wrong and e.g. an activity-restart might be needed.

Note that the UI thread can't be put to sleep or wait, since then the OK button in the dialog would not work at all.

Has anybody got an idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Has anybody got an idea how to achieve this?

Put your "do something to react individually to the Exception" in the dialog close-button handler, such as via  a `final Runnable`.

Comment: @manmal: It won't. However, the stuff you're trying to do post-dialog will wait until the user deals with the dialog, because you are only executing it once the user closes the dialog.

Comment: well that was not new to me, but thanks anyway. i guess the code which should not run can't be stopped until the user has ok'd. meaning i would either have to start an error-display-activity, or just live with the fact.

Comment: @manmal: "i guess the code which should not run can't be stopped until the user has ok'd" -- unless you have background threads or `postDelayed()` loops, not much will be going on while the dialog is on the screen. What precisely are you expecting to have running when there is nothing running but the dialog?

Comment: at least the currently running method (where the exception occurred) will continue to run. imagine a login method where some connection exception occurs (server offline even after several retries) - exception is thrown, dialog started, but the method continues ("could not login" toast is shown etc.) in an erroneous state - it shouldn't.

Comment: @manmal: "but the method continues... in an erroneous state" -- that is a problem with your code and your exception handler, then. The dialog has nothing whatsoever to do with this. All a blocking dialog would do is delay the method continuing in your erroneous state. You would have to clean things up at that point. The non-blocking dialog simply means you still have to clean things up at that point, in effect before the dialog actually appears (note: the dialog will not even be shown until you return control to Android from whatever callback you're in).

Comment: the thing is, i would like to decide within the dialog whether execution is continued. there are exceptions which allow continuation of execution, while some do not. i have thought about it and i think it's ok that the Activity stays in control of its own flow - if it handles the exception via the BaseActivity, it can choose to abort the method or continue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `UncaughtExceptionHandler`?

Refer this doc [Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)

Implement this interface and do the handling stuff in the callback `uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex)`

Comment: My post is about CAUGHT (checked) exceptions, not unchecked ones. I already employ BugSense for uncaught Exceptions.